# not:first-child applies to all element and not to first one

Tags: javascript, html, css

that is simple js gallery. I use `not:first-child` to shown only one photo one page is loaded. But it doesn't hide others photos. link: http://liebeundsprueche.com/kaley-cuoco-nackt/  (some photos are +18)

My goal is to hide hide all photos without first one, when page is loaded. After clicking on buttons it should show next or previuos pphotos normally. I don't understand what i wrote syntaxicali or logically wrong. JS works, css not.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
.mySlides not:first-child {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="btt"><button class="w3-button" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮ Prev</button> <button class="w3-button" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Next ❯</button></div>
<div class="w3-content">

  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/1.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/2.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/3.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/4.jpg" alt=Kaley Cuoco nackt ""></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/5.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/6.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/7.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/8.jpg" alt=Kaley Cuoco nackt ""></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/9.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/10.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/11.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/12.jpg" alt=Kaley Cuoco nackt ""></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/13.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/14.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/15.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/16.jpg" alt=Kaley Cuoco nackt ""></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/17.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/18.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/19.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/20.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt "></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/21.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt "></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/22.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt "></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Should it not be `:not`? Also, there should not be a space between `.mySlides` and `:not`. Space means children.

Comment: updated but nothing changed

Comment: check again your code please, they are not child of same parent ... each on is inside a div

Comment: should i use .w3-content:not:first-child{
    display:none !important;
}  ?

Comment: @ნიკახაჩიძე the reason its not working is because all your `img` are first child.

Comment: @ნიკახაჩიძე I have added an answer that will work with your existing structure. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have error in the syntax and second an error in the logic. You may notice that `.mySlides` are inside a div so they are not child of same parent so first-child will trigger **all** of them. you also need to remove `!important` or the JS code won't work as `!important` will have more priority then inline style.

So you need to make them inside the same div (they should have the same parent) and correct the CSS syntax and of `:not()` like this:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
.mySlides:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="btt"><button class="w3-button" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮ Prev</button> <button class="w3-button" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Next ❯</button></div>
<div class="w3-content">

  <div><img class="mySlides" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"><img class="mySlides" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/420/" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://lorempixel.com/420/400/" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://lorempixel.com/420/420/" alt=Kaley Cuoco nackt ""></div>

</div>
```

Comment: @ნიკახაჩიძე check again :) you need to remove important

Comment: @ნიკახაჩიძე and  i use only 3 images but you can add more of course

Comment: CAn i use it with p elements? also p and not img.

Comment: @TemaniAfif You should remove the script or at least `showDivs(slideIndex);` as this itself does the work.

Comment: @ნიკახაჩიძე yes you can, the only restriction is that you need to make the element used inside the same parent ... so it can be img, p or any element, but they should be at the same level

Comment: @Rajesh it's useless to remove it as OP is aware about it .. you can read in the question at the end `JS works, css not.` ... so am sure he want to add CSS as the JS is running at the end and maybe the image get shown a little before the JS is executed.

Comment: on your example, how can i add text to each images? i only think about div and img and o together in div. but it is not some level.....

Comment: in this case you create a div with text+image and make the `myslides` class go to the div and like that you don't change your CSS and JS ... so instead of the image you have you put div and inside the div put what you want ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues here.

The first is that you're trying to identify whether or not `.mySlides` is a first child. However, every `.mySlides` element is inside a single div, so it is ***always*** the first (and only) child. You cannot identify it that way.

You would need to target `.w3-content > div` instead to get all direct descendants of the container.

The other mistakes are in the pseudo-selectors. Once you have the right target, you need to use the format `:not(selector)` without any gap before it. So in this case, it would be `:not(:first-child)`.

In other words, you have added an extra space after `.mySlides`, removed a colon before `not`, and missed out the brackets around `:first-child`.

So, the correct CSS would be:

```
.w3-content > div:not(:first-child) { display: none; }
```

An alternative way would be to hide all the slides, and then show the first one:

```
.w3-content > div { display: none; }
.w3-content > div:first-child { display: block; }
```

You will also need to update your JS to target the right elements after this (by adding parentElement for example:

```
x[i].parentElement.style.display = "none";
```

and:

```
x[slideIndex - 1].parentElement.style.display = "inline";
```

Comment: the issue is that this won't work with his JS code, as he's targetting the image ... so maybe you should say that he need to adapt his code also

Comment: i know :) it's not for me it's for him ... if you hides divs is ok, but then his JS code works on image and not div, so he simply need to adjust it to work also with div .. simple clarification for him to understand

Comment: Comment deleted, I see what you mean. So yes, makes sense to change the JS also. Updated my answer to add the changes.

Comment: Yes Temani, it doesn' work whith my js code. CAn i you just please show me a link of very simple js gallery? like that that can work with many images?

Comment: I have just updated the answer to add the JS changes.

Answer (score 0):

As commented,

> Should it not be :not? Also, there should not be a space between .mySlides and :not. Space means children.
>
> the reason its not working is because all your img are first child

You can use `div.w3-content div:not(:first-child) img.mySlides` selector instead.

#### Idea

- Get all divs in `.w3-content` except first child. I'm directly using `div` but you should add a class and use it as `div.className`
- Hide `mySlides` in them.

**Sample:**

```css
div.w3-content div:not(:first-child) img.mySlides {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="btt"><button class="w3-button" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮ Prev</button> <button class="w3-button" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Next ❯</button></div>
<div class="w3-content">

  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/1.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/2.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/3.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/4.jpg" alt=Kaley Cuoco nackt ""></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/5.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/6.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/7.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/8.jpg" alt=Kaley Cuoco nackt ""></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/9.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/10.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/11.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/12.jpg" alt=Kaley Cuoco nackt ""></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/13.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/14.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/15.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/16.jpg" alt=Kaley Cuoco nackt ""></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/17.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/18.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/19.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt"></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/20.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt "></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/21.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt "></div>
  <div><img class="mySlides" src="/wp-content/images/22.jpg" alt="Kaley Cuoco nackt "></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/)

It should be like

```
.mySlides:not(:first-child){
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: check code please before posting answer ... they are not child of the same parent